# How to prevent browser from executing PHP code that i have added as sample/example on my page

Tags: php

I want to paste some PHP code samples on a web page However the browser will treat it as normal PHP code and will execute it rather than treating it as text. how can this be achieved... I hope the answer is very simple but has alluded me. I spent good about 2 hours on this.

Comment: How about some code? Or at least further clarification what exactly you want to achieve?

Answer (score 3):

Rather than using `<?php ... ?>` use `&lt;?php ... ?&gt;`

Comment: Ohhh... I see these are what stackoverflow also use. thanks a lot

Answer (score 1):

The browser doesn't execute your php code, your server does.
To output php code from a php page, do not include it inside the  block.

```
<html>
<?php
  echo 'this will show some example code';
?>
<code>
  echo 'this is some example code';
</code>
<?php
  echo 'that was some example code';
?>
</html>
```

You may need to use `<pre></pre>` rather than code tag, I'm not certain on it's browser support off the top of my head but it should be pretty well supported.

Answer (score 0):

PHP code is executed on a serverside, not in a browser. To prevent code from executing use [escape sequences](http://www.boulder.swri.edu/~joel/esc_chars.html)

Comment: Thnks a lot by browser I ment my browser.. Thanks am looking at escape sequence.

Comment: Yes seems like escaping is the way..thanks.. may be thats why my search in the google didnt gave any correct results since i should have looked for escaping seq

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
    highlight_file("file_to_format.php");
?>
```